# Getting server's baseurl without request object

Tags: node.js, express, request

I am running a cronjob on Express Server. This cron job access 3rd party API and fetch some data. To make the API (Oauth v2) call I need my server's `baseurl` (not `hostname` via `os` module).

Since its a cronjob there is no `request` object. Is it possible to get server's `baseurl` without `request` object directly exposed.

Comment: Since the baseurl does not change with requests, why don't you just set it up as a config / env variable?

Comment: Yeah I thought of that and it will be my last choice. But its not clean and there are 3 different server url depending upon `env`. @SwarajGiri

Comment: Then get the baseurl from whatever the env sets. That would be the correct base url right?

Comment: Its possible but not a dynamic approach. Does express save this info anywhere?

Comment: envs are available in `process.env` https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env

Comment: Not talking about `process.env`, I know I can use it for env variables. Does express store `baseUrl` any where?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90406/discussion-between-swaraj-giri-and-sushant).